# How to look up rows in certain condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I would like to search strange rows like below :

```
　　month
0  201605　　　　
1  201606
2  201607
3      08
4     nan
5  201610
```

For instance, I would like to extract rows with elements that is not 6 digits like below :

```
   month
3   08
4  nan
```

I have searched, but couldn't figure out how to extract rows.
How can I get this result?

Comment: How about `df[~(df.month > 10**5)]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your month column is of `str` type, you can use `.str.len()` to get the number of digits for each element and use the result for subsetting:

```
df[df.month.str.len() != 6]

# month
#3   08
#4  NaN
```